# Higher order SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithm, tensors

Does anyone know how to do a higher order SVD in Mathematica ? A good reference seems to be here http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/pubs/pubfiles/SAND2007-6702.pdf but I don't understand their formalism yet, maybe someone has already some experience with this in Mathematica and this could speed up the understanding. Thanks

Comment: The paper you reference has great illustrations, that make thinking about tensor decompositions quite intuitive.  Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Higher-order SVD (in sense of [Tucker decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition#Tucker_decomposition)) of the matrix $M$ with dimensions $d_1\times d_2\times\cdots\times d_n$ is

$$
M_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_N} = \sum_{j_1} \sum_{j_2}\cdots \sum_{j_N} s_{j_1,j_2,\dots,j_N} u^{(1)}_{i_1,j_1} u^{(2)}_{i_2,j_2} \dots u^{(N)}_{i_N,j_N},
$$
where $s$ is the core tensor and $u^{(i)}$ is the orthogonal matrix.

The matrix $u^{(i)}$ is left singular vectors of regular SVD of matrix $T$ with dimensions $d_i \times\prod_{j\neq i}d_j$ ($T$ is `Flatten` of $M$ over all dimensions except $i$-th). Therefore, high-order SVD is just a composition of  regular SVDs over each dimension of $M$

```
hoSVD[m_] := With[{d = ArrayDepth[m]}, 
  {Fold[Transpose[#1, RotateRight@Range[d]].#2 &, m, #], ConjugateTranspose /@ #} &@
    Table[Conjugate@First@SingularValueDecomposition@Flatten[m, {{i}, Delete[Range[d], i]}], {i, d}]]
```

It returns `{s, u}` where `s` is the core tensor and `u` is the list of orthogonal matrices

If $n=2$ it is regular SVD

```
m = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 4}];
{s, u} = hoSVD[m];
Max@Abs[m - Transpose@u[[1]].s.u[[2]]]
```

> 1.11022*10^-15

To generalize to the multidimensional case we need a generalization of the `Dot`

```
dot[s_, u_, n_] := Transpose[Transpose[s, Ordering[#]].u, #] &@Append[#, n] &@
     Delete[#, n] &@Range@ArrayDepth[s];
```

It is `Dot` over `n`-th dimension of `s`.

Now we can write

```
m2 = dot[dot[s, u[[1]], 1], u[[2]], 2];
Max@Abs[m - m2]
```

> 1.11022*10^-15

Multidimensional case

```
m = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 4, 5}];
{s, u} = hoSVD[m];
m2 = dot[dot[dot[s, u[[1]], 1], u[[2]], 2], u[[3]], 3];
Max@Abs[m - m2]
```

> 3.9968*10^-15

```
m = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {3, 4, 5, 6}];
{s, u} = hoSVD[m];
Max@Abs[Fold[dot[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, s, Transpose@{u, Range@Length[u]}] - m]
```

> 6.21725*10^-15

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for your time, your implementation is quite compact which is good. This can have applications to many fields.

Answer (score 8):

I worked on this topic today as I'm interested in it for an interpolation problem.

I followed the interlaced computation from the Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition) in the other answers (corresponding paper is [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/110836067)), and improved ybeltukov's answer. This allows the decomposition to be faster when the number of points is high and ranks are low, which can be a common case.

This [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.9222&rep=rep1&type=pdf) allowed me to understand how to use the decomposition for interpolation. Interpolating a tensor is basically the product of 1D-interpolations of singular vectors across indices (ie. of different columns of the us below) weighted by the core tensor (s). Given that the number of non zero values of the core tensor can be very small compared to the number of dimensions (if the data is not random), the interpolation algorithm can be made very fast.

We have for example

$$
M(x, y, z) = \sum_{j_1} \sum_{j_2} \sum_{j_3} s_{j_1,j_2,j_3} u^{(1)}_{j_1}(x) u^{(2)}_{j_2}(y) u^{(3)}_{j_3}(z)
$$

This can actually be useful for integrating a function as well, by integrating splines for example. So if the core tensor is indeed small it's possible to do high dimensional integrations very fast.

Here is the code

```
defaultTol=1.*^-10;
rankFunction[mat_,tol_:defaultTol]:=Length@Select[Diagonal@mat,Abs@#>tol&];

hoSVD2[m_,maxRank_:Infinity,rankF_:rankFunction]:=
    Module[{d,us,Ak,r,u2,u,w,v,rotatePermutation,flateningDimensions},
        d=ArrayDepth[m];
        flateningDimensions={{1},Delete[Range[d],1]};
        rotatePermutation=RotateRight@Range[d];

        Ak=m;
        us=
        Table[
            (*we flatten the dimensions other than the first one to have a matrix,and run an SVD on it*)
            {u,w,v}=SingularValueDecomposition[Flatten[Ak,flateningDimensions],UpTo[maxRank]];

            (*we keep the singular vectors corresponding to non zero singular values*)
            r=rankF@w;
            u2=u[[All,;;r]];

            (*we rotate the kth dimension with u2,and transpose Ak for the next iteration 
              in order to have the (k+1)th dimension as the leftmost one,
              multiplying with u2 can decrease the amount of data of Ak,thus accelerating next iterations*)
            Ak=Transpose[(ConjugateTranspose@u2).Ak,rotatePermutation];

            u2
            ,
            {k,d}
        ];

        (*s=Ak;*)
        {Ak,us}
    ];

(*u(n).s, multiplying s on the left across index n*)
dot2[s_,u_,n_]:=
Module[{perm,permInv},
    permInv=Range@ArrayDepth[s]//Delete[#,n]&//Prepend[#,n]&;
    perm=Ordering[permInv];
    Transpose[u.Transpose[s,perm],permInv]
];

(*Interpolation function*)
interpolateVector[v_,x_]:=Interpolation[v][x];
interpU[u_,i_,j_,x_]:=interpolateVector[u[[i,All,j]],x[[i]]];
interpS[s_,spos_,u_,x_]:=s[[Sequence@@spos]]*Times@@Table[interpU[u,i,spos[[i]],x],{i,Length@spos}];
interpM[s_,positiveS_,u_,x_]:=interpS[s,#,u,x]&/@positiveS//Total;
```

And examples

```
(*example data*)
f[x_,y_,z_]:=Cos[x+y+z] Exp[-0.03(z+y)];
nPoints=6;
m=Table[f[x,y,z],{x,Range[nPoints]},{y,Range[nPoints]},{z,Range[nPoints]}]*1.;

(*reconstruction of the original tensor, works with any number of indices*)
{s,u}=hoSVD2[m];
m2 = Fold[dot2[#, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]]&, s, Transpose@{u, Range@Length[u]}];
Max@Abs[m - m2]

(*interpolation example, works with any number of indices*)
x={1.8,4.2,2.2};
f@@x
positiveS=Position[s,x_/;Abs@x>0.00001];
interpM[s,positiveS,u,x]

(*hoSVD on a big tensor*)
nPoints2=100;
mBig=Table[f[x,y,z],{x,Range[nPoints2]},{y,Range[nPoints2]},{z,Range[nPoints2]}]*1.;
{s,u}=hoSVD2[mBig];//Timing(*finishes in a reasonable amount of time*)
```

Comment: You might want to give a second argument à la `UpTo[maxrank]` to `SingularValueDecomposition` in order to compute a truncated SVD. For example, in your `bigM` case, a maximal rank for 10 or so should reduce the time for SVD drastically without loosing anything of the approximation quality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've updated the function accordingly, even putting UpTo[Infinity] speeds up the computation massively. This is quite an impressive algorithm, in terms of what it can do compared to the time it takes.

Comment: Indeed, `UpTo[Infinity]` leads to a _massive_ speed up. Interesting... Thanks for letting be know!

Comment: The algorithm must be iterative and stop when singular values are too small.

Comment: Related: https://research.fb.com/fast-randomized-svd/

Comment: Thanks for the link. This might also be of interest if the tensor is given by a "sufficiently smooth" multivariate function: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-010-9103-x. It uses a heuristical strategy to reduce computations effort by picking only few "row" of the multidimensional tensor for the computations. That is _not all entries of the original tensor need to be known_. E.g. a $N \times N \times N$ tensor my be rank-reduced with only $O(N)$ time and memory. It is not always guaranteed to work with the heuristic strategy (pretty similar to randomized methods).

Comment: However, IIRC, the method is guaranteed to work when _all_ entries of the initial are known.

Comment: See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189913) where I implemented the algorithm for matrices.

Comment: Interesting, thank you

Comment: Related regarding knowledge graphs, hosvd is really powerful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09590

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a perhaps more accessible [description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition).

> In multilinear algebra, there does not exist a general decomposition method for multi-way arrays (also known as N-arrays, higher-order arrays, or data-tensors) with all the properties of a matrix singular value decomposition (SVD).
>
> A matrix SVD simultaneously computes
>
> (a) a rank-R decomposition and
>
> (b) the orthonormal row/column matrices.
>
> These two properties can be
>   captured separately by two different decompositions for multi-way
>   arrays. Property (a) is extended to higher order by a class of closely
>   related constructions known collectively as CP decomposition (named
>   after the two most popular and general variants, CANDECOMP and
>   PARAFAC). Such decompositions represent a tensor as the sum of the
>   n-fold outter products of rank-1 tensors, where n is the dimension of
>   the tensor indices.
>
> Property (b) is extended to higher order by a
>   class of methods known variably as Tucker3, N-mode SVD, and N-mode
>   principal component analysis (PCA). (This article will use the general
>   term "Tucker decomposition".) These methods compute the othonormal
>   spaces associated with the different axes (or modes) of a tensor. The
>   Tucker decomposition is also used in multilinear subspace learning as
>   multilinear principal component analysis. This terminology was coined
>   by P. Kroonenberg in the 1980s, but it was later called multilinear
>   SVD and HOSVD (higher-order SVD) by L. De Lathauwer. Historically,
>   much of the interest in higher-order SVDs was driven by the need to
>   analyze empirical data, especial in psychometrics and chemometrics. As
>   such, many of the methods have been independently invented several
>   times, often with subtle variations, leading to a confusing
>   literature. Abstract and general mathematical theorems are rare
>   (though see Kruskal[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition) with regard to the CP decomposition); instead,
>   the methods are often designed for analyzing specific data types. The
>   2008 review article by Kolda and Bader[2](http://smc.vnet.net/MathTensor.html) provides a compact summary
>   of the history of these decompositions, and many references for
>   further reading.

Also, see this [package](http://smc.vnet.net/MathTensor.html) for MathTensor.  I think it got updated for v8.

> "The creation of MathTensor will open a new chapter in the development of all fields of science and engineering that use serious tensor analysis." - Stephan Wolfram

All this said, it's hard to answer such a general question.  Try to provide a specific example and some code of what you've tried.

Comment: This is more of a long comment than an answer I suppose...

Comment: @J.M. -- Acknowledged, just trying to help the question down the road towards an answer.